# Is it legal to travel with a suitcase full of physical cash (worthless banknotes) from Venezuela?

Tags: legal, money, venezuela

## I want to buy some cash.

[image]

https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-45246409

These banknotes are so cool, they are worth much more as collectibles.

Is it legal to travel with a suitcase full of physical banknotes out of Venezuela?

Comment: I honestly don't think there's much value in these things, even as collectibles; a collector can get as many as they want for virtually nothing anyway, so anyone really interested in them has probably done so already. If there is any collectible value, it's in the notes that were made obsolete by the hyperinflation. For example, I have a pristene Zimbabwean $1 banknote from shortly before that currency went into freefall. That banknote is almost certainly worth a lot more as a collectible than a hundred trillion dollar note printed a few years later.

Comment: Wether it is legal or not, there will almost necessarily be a certain amount of complications. Large amounts of physical cash are very often tied to drugs, money laundering or other criminal activities. Any policeman or border agent would want to look deeply into why you have this money and where it comes from.

Comment: @Spudley, there is a market. So there is value. The amount of people whilling to pay for box of Venezuela money is important. But the cost of those stack is incredibly high on the market. It's more about having a large stack of money than buying premium low denomination note for collection. The amouth of people that wish to buy a cubic meter of worth less banknote for the price of shipping is high.

Comment: Would make a neat replacement for monopoly money.  Maybe they could even come out with a version of Monopoly that uses "Real Money" and Venezuelan landmarks?

Comment: I take you are asking whether Venezuela has any laws against people flying out with banknotes, rather than whether your home country has laws against taking banknotes in?

Comment: **Make sure you check out arielCo's answer below, he's from the country. Trying to leave with that money might land you in very serious trouble, no matter whether it's really worth anything or not. The authorities are out there to look for cases like this to use in their propaganda. You can easily end up on the front page of newspapers if caught.**

Comment: Have you considered mailing it to your address in your home country?

Comment: @JustinLardinois the post and private couriers don't accept cash in parcels.

Comment: @arielCo some services might prohibit it, but others just discourage it. Just as an example, [it's legal to send cash through the US Postal Service](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/sending-cash-u-s-mail-illegal/).

Comment: It's a common strategy to buy worthless money, wash and bleach it, and reprint the paper (which is not ordinary paper) with some other currency. So, by trying to export large amounts of worthless money, you will inevitably attract a lot of attention from certain governmental circles.

Comment: @arielCo but how would they even know it contains cash?

Answer (score 82):

It's a **really bad idea**, so much that I registered just to warn you (I live in Venezuela). When there was a severe shortage of cash the government blamed it on banknotes being [extracted through the Colombian border for sale at a profit](https://www.google.com/search?q=contrabando%20efectivo%20venezuela) and "hoarding". Arrests were highly publicized, which additionally helped support the conspiracy theory of an "economic war" waged from abroad to destabilize the country.

Now imagine a foreign-looking type caught with a heap of cash: official news outlets are going to have a field day with the [arrest photograph](http://www.caraotadigital.net/sucesos/fueron-detenidos-por-tener-21-millones-de-bolivares-en-efectivo/):

[image: men arrested for having large sums of cash]

> Los tres hombres se desplazaban en dos vehículos por la carretera nacional San Félix-Upata. Los cuerpos de seguridad, en un trabajo de inteligencia, frustraron el presunto contrabando de extracción de esta cantidad de papel moneda.
>
> The three men were traveling on two vehicles down the San Félix-Upata highway. Security forces, in an intelligence operation, frustrated the presumed extraction contraband of these many banknotes.

In a good scenario, you'll spend a few hours in "the little room" and be relieved of your valuables by the local authorities before they let you go.

I agree that the banknotes are pretty, but please take just a few of each denomination. If anyone asks, it's left over from your daily purchases.

**General advice**: don't come without a trusted local friend willing to accompany you everywhere, preferably in a car. I'm not exaggerating: Caracas has the 2nd-4th highest murder rate in the world, and $100 can feed a family of four for a month. There are official no-go ["peace zones"](https://www.insightcrime.org/news/brief/despite-security-failures-venezuela-peace-zones-remain/) for law enforcement where kidnappers take their hostages.

--

BTW, the photo in your question illustrates the amount of cash you needed to buy that toilet paper roll before the Bolívar was redefined so amounts would have 5 less figures (1 new "Bolívares Soberanos" = 100,000 old "Bolívares Fuertes").

Comment: I don't get it. There's no way the toilet paper sold for that much as the physical value of that pile of notes is higher than the roll.

Comment: [Yes it is](https://www.news.com.au/news-story/6cd362993e4eed79aeeb372f6521b21c) (those are old "Bolívares Fuertes", and the new unit is worth 100,000 of those). Another example: a stick of French bread costs BsS 60 = BsF 6,000,000.

Comment: The notes can be used as the paper.

Comment: They'd be pretty lousy as TP, but that's the implicit joke. Even with the new unit some bills aren't worth the paper they're printed on. Ever seen photos of cash being burned in stoves and fireplaces? Hyperinflation does that.

Comment: The people at the Caracas sewage plant would be like "darn it, the filter's clogged again. What is all this stuff?"

Comment: You live in Venezuela? Can I send you some PayPal / crypto / cash in the post and you send me 20kg of worthless cash? I’m not doing anything illegal here, I don’t think Venezuelan government will chase me in Europe for that... **Loveveveve!!!!!!!!!11111oneoneone** (I never planned to actually come due to kidnapping risk, “peace zone” what a term, I just wanted to know if it is legal or not)

Comment: Wait a minute. Wouldn't people acquiring paper currency and leaving the country be good for the local economy? You are removing a bunch of cash and creating a demand for the money, increasing its value. The case you cited is effectively the opposite of the current situation

Comment: @MichalStefanow, what's illegal depends a lot on interpretation and the Supreme Court is stuffed with loyals (its chief justice did time for murder). Couriers won't mail cash; it just occured to me that you _can_ buy Venezuelan banknotes by the kilo in Cúcuta, a Colombian border town. Seriously, we don't trifle with these guys without being connected.

Comment: @OganM, they print money like crazy - you have no idea. Also, I just read money burning is deflationary only [“If the economy is at full employment equilibrium”](http://enwp.org/Money_burning).

Comment: @arielCo im confused. If the money is traded for currency from some other country isn't just just replacing a million small bills with one large bill? I would think the federal government would be trying to bring them all to the mints so that they can be swapped with higher denomination bills? It's not like the foreign currency isn't worth anything there. I'm guessing it's more of a way for the government to establish control and keep foreigners away?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, I'm not sure if you mean buying the obsolete bills or the current ones, but in any case you're dealing with a government more interested in propaganda for the unwashed populace than their actual well-being, and yes, control.

Comment: @arielCo old bills that are worthless I meant

Comment: @OganM I once worked on finance lines for an international organization that did fundraising in Venezuela among other countries.  One time, a major accounting discrepancy turned out to be because someone had recorded Venezuelan donations in our books according to the “official” exchange rate—not knowing that the rate you can *actually* get for Venezuelan currency was about 1/3 the official value. In other words, **you’re right: the value of a currency depends on its potential circulation and the Venezuelan government’s restriction on currency leaving their borders reduces its value.** Oh well.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, still a risk. They may say you were planning on bleaching them to use the paper for counterfeiting (an actual thing). Regardless of soundness you'll look good on the papers. Hundreds of arrests have been made over dozens of made-up coup and magnicide plots.

Comment: It must be a strange life to have to warn people not to come to your country because they'd get killed, kidnapped or stripped of their stuff by law enforcement.

Comment: @arielCo of course, I'm just thinking that replacing several small bills with larger bills is a common desire when a new currency is put out. Like how a bank would prefer thousands of dollars rather than millions of pennies.

Answer (score 32):

Yes.

[Source](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/VE-Venezuela-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) (IATA):

> Currency
>
> Currency Import regulations: Local currency (Bolivar Soberano-VES) and
>   foreign currencies: no restrictions
>
> Currency Export regulations: Local currency (Bolivar Soberano-VES) and
>   foreign currencies: no restrictions

(Though, given Venezuela's current situation, who knows what will happen in practice if they decide to check your suitcase.)

Comment: You'll also want to check for restrictions, limits, taxes, etc, imposed by your destination country.  And if they have limits or duties based on the value of the money, you'll have to hope they agree with your estimation that it's "worthless".

Comment: @NateEldredge The stash of money in the picture is the price for the toilet paper roll next to it.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Yes, I had gathered that.  But it's possible that customs officials in the destination country may not value it accurately - e.g. based on an unrealistic standard or outdated exchange rate (with hyperinflation, the money may have had considerable value a short time ago).  Venezuela has also apparently issued a new currency since that article was written, and customs officials may mix up the values of the old and new bolivars.  Just a warning that even if everything is legal, there may still be hassle.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo in reality or in theory? Many countries have an official exchange rate which is quite different from the real value of their currency. Wouldn't be surprised if that's the case with Venezuela as well.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. Almost every country requires currency or other financial instruments with value exceeding something like $10,000 USD or 10,000 EUR to be declared to Customs on arrival. You're typically allowed to enter with it, but you'll have to talk to Customs. I have no idea how they'd deal with Venezuela's worthless currency, though. Probably depends somewhat on the Customs official's sense of humor.

Comment: @NateEldredge I assume taxes and duties will not exceed the amount of money exported, in which case you don’t have to deal with unrealistic exchange rates by paying with the local currency notes you would have otherwise exported.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: No, you use the stash before using the toilet paper.

Comment: It might be a huge problem if the customs officer thinks you are importing a lot of cash. In my country, italy, a guy was fined a million euro for having 3 billion of zimbabwe dollars. It was worth like 5 euro, but according to the customs agent, it was worth 4 million euro on xe.com. Can you trust the customs officer on the exchange rate? https://milano.repubblica.it/cronaca/2010/06/15/foto/le_tre_banconote_da_4_milioni_e_mezzo-4856076/1/  (sure, then the guy has proved back in court that the money was worthless, but it was long and expensive)

Comment: @Magnetic_dud if they thought it was worth 4 million euro then why didn't the officer simply confiscate 1/4 of the zimbabwe dollars? Surely the only logical policy with fining for not declaring money would be to just confiscate that amount from the undeclared money....

Comment: Please see my answer for why this is a terrible idea that may land the asker in jail.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: You have to settle fines in legal tender. Zimbabwean dollars are not legal tender in Italy.

Comment: @MastaBaba if they are not legal tender then you cannot logically be fined for bringing in too much cash. I'm not saying that the law currently allows it. I'm saying that there should've been the option to confiscate the "valuable" item being claimed as too high of a value. No different than if someone had tried to bring in an expensive vase without declaring. Confiscating the vase itself seems more logical than having to then worry about arguing in a court as to the value of said vase and whether the fine (and/or tax) was too high.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Though this quickly deteriorates to chat, the point is that fines need to be paid in a form of payment accepted by the institution levying the fine. The Italian state will not accept Zimbabwean dollars for any fine they levy. In addition, I'm not sure sure that confiscation would have been sufficient; to compare, someone smuggling, say, live animals across borders, and caught, gets the animals confiscated on top of a fine, or even jail time.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: In general it's not wise to rely on “official” information when visiting 3rd world countries, because it may be outdated or inaccurate. IATA won't tell you about arbitrary searches and detentions for extortion, or week-old “rules”. Did you know that customs are confiscating drones and PC video cards?

Comment: @arielCo: In case you are responding to my question on the down vote, I do point out in my answer that your mileage may vary. However, OP only asked about legality, not about practice.

Answer (score 26):

[MastaBaba's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126623/34910) addressed the legality of exporting currency.

This answer deals with importing currency. Most times you have to **declare currency** that you are bringing in. The limits vary. The USA says you have to declare more than the equivalent of US$10,000, for example.

The first problem is that a border agent seeing your suitcase of cash won’t know how much it’s worth and whether it’s over the limit. They might be forced to **count it all** even if you’re under the limit in order to file a report, which will delay you considerably. You might miss your connecting flight.

The second issue is that most paper currency has trace amounts of drugs on it. So large amounts of cash tend to get flagged by the **drug sniffing dogs**. So again expect delays and having to make explanations when this happens.

Finally, in the USA, large amounts of cash have often been seized by state and local governments under the doctrine of **civil forfeiture**. If you are driving around with a suitcase of cash and get pulled over and a drug sniffing dog finds the cash, you may find it seized by the local police and you have to defend the cash against the seizure in a local court.

TLDR: I hope you’re not bringing the suitcase of cash to the USA.

Comment: Judging by the pictures in the OP's linked article, $10000 USD in bolívars would be much more than a suitcase; several truckloads sound more in the ballpark.

Comment: TLDR is usually placed at top to help avoid a long read 

Comment: It's not clear that currency typically has enough drug residue for a dog to detect; I'm seeing many sources that suggest this is a myth.  However, there are also sniffer dogs that are specifically trained to smell currency.

Comment: I would also wonder, as I commented on MastaBaba's answer, whether you can be confident that customs authorities in you destination country will understand the cash has very little value.  With hyperinflation, if they're using old exchange rates, they might think the value is over some legal limit, even if its true value is not.

Comment: I found conflicting claims on the drug dog question, so [I asked it on Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/does-normal-paper-currency-contain-enough-narcotics-residue-to-attract-a-drug-sn).

Comment: @ajd plus thanks to the inflation if you get 10k USD worth of bank notes, by the time you get the airport, you'll have less than 10k USD worth of bank notes!

Comment: @NateEldredge my understanding of that issue is that it happens but is rare. Just as photographic film sometimes triggering bomb residue scanners.

Comment: @jwenting, on the other hand, if you're traveling with old nitrocellulose film stock, I sure *hope* it triggers the bomb scanners.

Comment: $US10k = 2.486 billion bolivars. Shown in the image above is 1000 bolivar note around 1 gram each. Weight of VEF2.5 B = 2.5 metric tonnes.

Comment: @RavindranathAkila: not always. While I find it logical to see it at the top, Reddit for instance systematically has it at the bottom.

Comment: @Coomie That still relies on the US border agent (a) knowing that, and (b) caring. To which I say "meh"...

Comment: @Mark yeah, but not modern slide film (which did it quite often for me when flying).

Comment: Not only can cash carry traces of drugs, they can carry **significant amounts** of drugs. You can soak sturdy paper and clothes in solvated drugs as a method of carrying drugs here and there. I would not buy bolivars in a large quantity and transport them to the US - the "traces" of drugs can be enough to land you in federal prison... Besides, the bolivar is not going to be collectible anytime soon - the supply is waaaaay too high. Which is reflected, of course, in their value.

Comment: Please don't just write "the other answer". When you wrote it, I'm sure it was obvious which answer you were talking about. As I write this, there are five "other answers" and the only way to figure out which one you meant would be to go through the timestamps. Instead, write "[username]'s answer" and link to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "civil forfeiture"? What gives local police the right to take property when a crime was not being committed? Is it illegal to carry certain amounts of money?

Comment: Re: "Count it all"  What is the size of a bolívar fuerte compared to a US bill for example? It could be a requirement that they check each bill, at least quickly, to make sure you aren't trying to smuggle a real currency of value in with the bolivars.

Comment: @DavidRicherby better yet don't refer to other answers for information this answer should provide on its own.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've submitted an edit suggestion to do just that.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don't see much point in duplicating content from other answers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby well then don't reference the other answer at all and just let others come to the realization that this answer doesn't cover that aspect of the content. The reason I say this is that just like dead links an answer can be removed.

Comment: I think traces of drugs are not an issue.

Answer (score 12):

This is a big no-no, don't do it!

You would be going directly to jail, as currently any person with a lot of money in cash is a target.

https://www.lapatilla.com/2018/08/20/detienen-a-hombre-con-250-millones-de-bolivares-fuertes-en-efectivo/

https://www.lapatilla.com/2018/05/11/detienen-a-mujer-con-470-millones-de-bolivares-en-efectivo-en-anzoategui/

https://www.lapatilla.com/2018/06/07/pillados-detienen-a-seis-hombres-por-reventa-de-efectivo-en-anzoategui/

https://www.google.com/search?ei=RnQFXPqfNcag5wLJkoTADQ&q=la+patilla+efectivo+detienen&oq=la+patilla+efectivo+detienen&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.39887.39887..40133...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.naOCWLEdqqk

I'm Venezuelan.

Comment: This clam needs to be backed up with evidence of some kind.

Comment: @coteyr Isn't every link provided evidence of some kind? I have some more in my answer. Please don't downvote lightly.

Comment: Usually, links are good references but you want to include the most critical parts of the linked content to help protect against link rot. But the links you provided (one of which is just google) don't seem to be about the bringing currency into another country, but about selling the currency for an inflated value. (I had to translate so that may not be 100% correct)

Comment: I added a quote + translation to my answer instead

Comment: @coteyr Doesn't *"These banknotes are so cool, they are worth much more as collectibles"* imply that OP intends to sell the currency for an inflated value?

Comment: @coteyr: it's very irresponsible to act so with this question. Two Venezuelans have answered with dire warnings that leaving the country with larger amounts of cash, no matter whether it's really worth anything or not, is considered very seriously by the authorities in order to promote their own propaganda. Perpetrators are caught and widely publicized in state media. Please, allow them to be informed enough to warn other people and don't downplay their warnings. Do the exact opposite by all means you have available here.

Comment: @coteyr no they aren't. The links are saying that people were merely carrying a large amount of cash and charged with "economic crimes" for attempting take their own money across the border. Statements such as the "citizens responsibility when having a large amount of money in their possession" lead me to believe it is not about the money itself being sold but rather that the government wants the citizens to turn in any large amounts of money in their possession. It definitely sounds like a bad situation there. I wouldn't try bringing more than one stack out of that country if that.

Comment: @LordFarquaad depends on whether it is for a personal collection.

Answer (score 11):

Venezuela has a multi-tier exchange rate. According to [xe.com](https://www.xe.com/currency/vef-venezuelan-bol%C3%ADvar#additionalinfo) the official exchange rate is 9.9875 VEF/USD as of May 2017. The black market rate is approximately 80,000 VEF/USD so anything over a US dollar or two at the black market rate will exceed $10K USD at the official rate. So better to proactively declare the currency at customs on entry unless the official rate is updated to something more realistic.

I would be a bit concerned about changing regulations on the export of currency.

In my experience, countries with capital controls tend to be sensitive about import and export of currency. For example Taiwan did not allow import and export of their currency, though they stopped short of actually inspecting wallets.

Comment: "countries with capital controls tend to be sensitive about import and export of currency." You are right, this used to be the case with China before 2009, and it is still the case in Cuba.

Answer (score 3):

First: [no restriction on currency export](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/VE-Venezuela-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm). So you can **depart** with any amount of Bolivares.

Second: most countries do not enforce a limit of import, but a limit on how much currency to import **silently**, without obligation to declare. Those limits are always defined in the destination country's local currency, e.g. 10K $ or €.
Considering that the Bolivar is a hyper-inflated currency **and** that the picture clearly displays (qualitatively, not quantitatively) how worth is that currency. No offense to Venezuelans.

Then: **in general**, it's not illegal to bring cash abroad. You may move any amount of money as soon as you stop at customs and state "I want to declare cash". They will have you fill forms at very minimum. Europe does not apply taxes to declared currency.

Conclusion: a suitcase full of Venezuelan cash, **is mostly legal**, at least in major destinations. Please state your destination to let me modify the answer accordingly.

I don't know how big should a suitcase be to fit 10K€ equivalent of Bolivares. If the countervalue is below 10K€, you can proceed to the green area. In case you are stopped, you will be let go after counting the cash. If the total value exceeds 10K€ you **are required** to stop and declare.

Caveat: expect questions. Custom officers pick up people at random. Expect them to count the bills until it is proven that you are below the legal limit. They will start from assuming you are trafficking cash. You *may* want to volunteer for an inspection to ensure trust. This will cost you time.

Caveat 2: dogs are trained, and excellently effective, at detecting cash too more than drugs. Another reason to hail to a customs officer and volunteer.

Comment: Is there any harm in declaring it anyway?  "I have 100 million bolivaras fuertas, valued at $345.”  The first reaction of the agent will be "Fuertas!? Won't that fill a suitcase?"  "Indeed it does..."

Comment: Absolutely no harm. Personally, I have never had information, hint or evidence that a traveller volunteering for customs may be treated with suspect. If I was a customs officer I would either think 1) he is dragging my attention to have a smuggler pass the green line uncovered or 2) he is really too paranoid at the rules

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ "If I was a customs officer" which, presumably, you're not. So your speculation about how you would react as a customs officer (possibly ignoring your training in the process) is exactly that: speculation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that may be true but the only other option is that someone is declaring the cash simply out of malice which couldn't make sense. Even if it were, what's the customs officer going to do? Arrest you for declaring something that didn't need declaring?