# When traveling to Venezuela, what currency should I carry with me

Tags: money, exchange, venezuela

I am planning a trip to Venezuela, but I don't know what kind of currency I should carry with me. Can I take US Dollars? Do I have to exchange my money to Venezuelan bolivars?

I see a lot of posts about the exchange rate on the black market inside Venezuela, but I still don't understand if I will be allowed to spend my US Dollars directly (without exchanging them to bolivars first).

I would really appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126621/is-it-legal-to-travel-with-a-suitcase-full-of-physical-cash-worthless-banknotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USD are not legal tender in Venezuela. Carry your dollars along and exchange when you get there. With the current situation there [and astronomical inflation](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-venezuela-economy/venezuela-annual-inflation-tops-1-million-pct-in-november-congress-idUSKBN1O91WT), it does not make sense to exchange your currency prior to arrival.